# What does my QQ Plot tell me if I have 4 variables?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, quantile

I have a model:

```
Model <- lm(Offensive.Score ~ FirstDown+ThirdDownPct+RushYds+PassYds, data = NFL.Team)
```

I have done crazy research on QQ Plots and understand that they are standardized points.
I still have no idea how that translates to my data though.

Above, I have a model that tries to predict the final score of the offensive team
with variables:

```
# x1:Num of offensive team's first downs.
# x2:Percent of offensive team's plays that get to the third down.
# x3:Yards gained during rushes.
# x4:Yards gained during passes.
```

My qqPlot shows right-skewness.

What does this mean?

I thought finding if something was skewed only applied to ONE variable but I have 4?

Thank you!

Comment: I was under the impression that QQ plots can only show one variable. Are you sure there aren't four separate plots? Or maybe multiple lines on the one plot?

Comment: A QQ plot shows the residuals from your model against a line that is the theoretical values from a normal distribution. It is not a plot for specific variables but rather a way of diagnosing whether or not the whole model is appropriate. As your outcome is a count variable, i.e. it only takes non-negative integer values, you could try a passion GLM to see if that is a better model for the data.

Comment: @sjp, could you provide some examples of GLM models for count variables? I know that family="binomial" would work for factors/logistic regressions but I've never heard of models for count variables. I thought a regular lm() would work.

Comment: Hi @Antonio , I had a typo in my comment there, but I wanted to recommend a Poisson GLM. This link seems useful: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-poisson-regression-in-r/